# Facebook app with fluid canvas (width)

Tags: facebook, width, facebook-apps, facebook-canvas

I´m trying to set fluid canvas for facebook app, but something is wrong. I found instuction how-to: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/549/

I used the same HMTL code from instruction to test it, but I´m doing something wrong. 
In settings, exactly "Select how your app integrate with facebook" panel I set canvas width and height to fluid, filled in "Canvas URL" and "Secure canvas URL" and saved it. In HTML code I changed my APP ID that´s all.

Then I put "Canvas Page" url http://apps.facebook.com/MY_APP/ to browser, but according to facebook app doesn´t exist or there´s a mistake.

My goal is to reach the same width as in instruction is the blue background.

Please help me, I´m looking for solution for 3 days.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok I found mistake, Canvas URL is my domain :D it´s working finally :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are pointing the URLs to your website and make sure the links are working.